# Запуск бота в фоне в приложении на django

Tags: django

Создаю django приложение. Есть необходимость запустить бота, который сможет работать в фоне. Он должен быть не только всегда запущен, но так же нужна возможность взаимодействовать с ним в ходе обработки запроса. Каким образом это реализуется в django?

Comment: Запускаете бота, и через функции python с ним общаетесь... Какой ответ Вы хотите получить на столь размытый вопрос? Не понятна суть и цель, где должен отображаться, должен ли вообще...

Comment: Запустить не проблема. Например можно использовать библиотеку subprocess в init одного из приложений django. Что с этим дальше делать не понял из вашего вопроса

Comment: Если, например хотите заложить какую то логику поведения бота при запросах пользователя на сервер - лучше всего использовать функционал middleware, этот код выполняется каждый раз ещё до обработки url.

Comment: python?Если не сложно, не могли бы вы объяснить, как это общение реализовать через функционал
Изначально я использовал flask, где в коде просто создавал инстанс бота как глобальный объект. Это не очень вписывается в концепцию django, поэтому вопрос был большей степенью о том, как создать глобальные объект при запуске django приложения, и через что потом к нему обращаться. Сейчас я посмотрю про упомянутое вами middleware - возможно оно

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение: можно создать сервис с ботом с помощью библиотеки rpyc. В таком случае бот всегда работает, а когда при запросе когда надо провзаимодействовать с ботом можно просто подключиться к сервису.